# Why do I get: Type TypeError: $el is undefined on add_widget method call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I bind a function to add widgets to a button through jQuery:

```
$('#slide_out_bar button').click(function(){
     test();
});

function test(){
   gridster.add_widget("<li><h1>Test</h1></li>");
}
```

When I click the button `test()` gets called but I get the error: `Type TypeError: $el is undefined`, printed in the console and no widget is added to the `gridster` element.

But if I simply call `test()` from a script tag in the HTML file it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   test();
</script>
```

I really don't get why this happens, does anyone have any ideas?

There is of course more to my code than this but I thought these were the most relevant sections. If you think some other parts of my code could somehow impact `gridster` I will post more of it.

EDIT: Here is all of my javascript code.

```
var gridster;

function initiate_gridster(){
  $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    max_cols: 4,
    max_rows: 3,
    min_cols: 4,
    widget_margins: [6, 6], 
    widget_base_dimensions: [300, 300]
  });
  gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster'); 
  gridster.$el.on('click', '.delete',function(event){
      remove_widget($(this));
  });
  return gridster;
}

function remove_widget(widget_elem){
  var widget = widget_elem.parents('li');  
  var data_id = widget[0].attributes['data-id']

  if(data_id == null){
    console.log("Cannot remove widget. Widget lacks 'data-id' attribute.");
    return;
  }

  var id = data_id.value

  var res = gridster.remove_widget(widget);

  $.post('remove_widget',{data_id: id}, function(data){
      console.log("Removed widget: " + id + "=" + data.message);
  });
} 



function test(){
  console.log("TEST");
  var grid = initiate_gridster();
  grid.add_widget("<li data-id='1'><div class='delete'>|||<div><h1 id='test' >Test</h1></li>",1,1); 
}
```

Comment: When and when is `gridster` defined? It would help to see the entire page so the code is in context :)

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or it didn't happen : ))

Comment: looks fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/41h7n0f6/1/

Comment: I will update the post with my code.

The thing is I can't really recreate it. On fiddle it works and when I do it in a dummy application it works. The only way I can get it to work in my application is by recreating the gridster object from scratch, a la : 
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
      max_cols: 4,
      max_rows: 3,
      min_cols: 4,
      widget_margins: [6, 6],
      widget_base_dimensions: [300, 300]
    }).data('gridster');

And then calling gridster.add_widget.

Comment: I am guessing that I am loosing the context of the original declaration of gridster somewhere along the way but I don't really know how or what to do about it.